# continous console error with my jQuery auto complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The below is not running and I am constantly getting the `Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function(anonymous function) @ global.js:80j @ jquery.min.js:2k @ jquery.min.js:2`' which is targeting the line with '        `})(jQuery);` called. I have tried reorganizing my external scripts in the `<head>` of the document, and tried using a JS lint, alas I continue to get this error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function($, undefined) {
    $.widget("app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
      _create: function() {
        if(this.element.is("select")) {
          var self = this;
          this.original = this.element.hide();
          this.element = $("<input/>").insertAfter(this.original);
          this.options.source = function(request, response) {
            var filter = $.ui.autocomplete.filter,
              $options = self.original.find("option"),
              result = $options.map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
              });
            response(filter(result, request.term));
          };
        }
        this._super("_create");
      },
      _destroy: function() {
        this._super("_destroy");
        this.element.remove();
        this.original.show();
      }
    });
  })(jQuery);
  $(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you passing `jQuery` as an argument *inside* a function that already assumes the existence of the `$` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `jQuery` variable to a newly created function because `$` already has the reference to `jQuery` function. You got an error because function `$` doesn't return a function when a function is passed as the first argument.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.widget("app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      if(this.element.is("select")) {
        var self = this;
        this.original = this.element.hide();
        this.element = $("<input/>").insertAfter(this.original);
        this.options.source = function(request, response) {
          var filter = $.ui.autocomplete.filter,
            $options = self.original.find("option"),
            result = $options.map(function() {
              return $(this).val();
            });
          response(filter(result, request.term));
        };
      }
      this._super("_create");
    },
    _destroy: function() {
      this._super("_destroy");
      this.element.remove();
      this.original.show();
    }
  });
  $(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete();
  });
});
```

Comment: Well spotted. Really easy to see with a simplified version of that part of the OP's code, something like this: `$(function() {})()`, but I didn't notice it in the full version till you pointed it out.

Comment: I am getting this error now with your suggestion: jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: f.getClientRects is not a function